# What is the way to color the Autocomplete chips in MUI reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to color the [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) from MUI like the way i have described below based on some if conditions. Couldn’t find a way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocomplete component has `renderTags` property which takes an array of selected values and return chips. Therefore, you can customize the chip color (by using predefined theme colors via `color` prop or setting background color with `sx` prop) based on your condition:

```
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        renderTags={(value: readonly string[], getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
            <Chip
              key={index}
              variant="outlined"
              label={option}
              sx={{background: value === "A" ? 'red' : 'green'}}
            />
          ))
        }
       ...other props
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

add `MuiChip-label` class in css

```
.MuiChip-label
{
   color:#fff !important;
}
```